# Map custom form fields to Contact form fields and submit programmatically

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Drupal 8: I have created a custom form and a contact form with the same fields. I would like to map custom form fields to contact form fields and submit the contact form manually from the custom form submit handler.

I am able to get the contact form entity in the custom form submit handler but not sure how to use it.

Any help would be appreciated!

NOTE: I have some complex layout and limitations to couldn't use the contact form directly.

Comment: Did you find a way to implement this?